# Find carrier info in use, not the SIM one

Tags: android, ios, core-telephony, carrier

Is it possible to get information about the Carrier currently in use?
CoreTelefony gives back information about the SIM carrier.

I haven't found any article on internet talking about this topic. Since the SIM can be the same also when the user moves in other countries, I would like to check the current network information the phone is using.

Any chance to achieve this result?

I'm interested in both iOS and Android code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[I ran into this problem a while back](https://stackoverflow.com/q/27135079/3983677), and I managed to find a way that works for my purposes. It's not pretty and not future proof, it is also not documented. But I do currently have an app in the AppStore that uses this.

Oh, and it's only tested on iOS 7.0 - 8.2!

So yeah, for iOS I know it's possible to find the [MMC and MNC](http://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mobile_country_code/), and that way you find the country and provider:

```
// This is the location of the operator symlink
static NSString * operatorPListSymLinkPath = @"/var/mobile/Library/Preferences/com.apple.operator.plist";

// Here we get the path where the symlink points to
NSFileManager * fileManager = [NSFileManager defaultManager]
NSError * error;
NSString * operatorPListPath = [fileManager destinationOfSymbolicLinkAtPath:operatorPListSymLinkPath error:&error];
```

The operator path contains a few numbers, of which the first 3 are the MCC (Mobile Country Code) of the provider and the few after that is the MNC (Mobile Network Code)

I just wanted to find the country (MCC), so I used this:

```
operatorPListPath = [operatorPListPath stringByTrimmingCharactersInSet:[[NSCharacterSet characterSetWithCharactersInString:@"1234567890"] invertedSet]];
NSString * countryMCC = [operatorPListPath substringToIndex:3];
```

All you need is a MCC > Country dictionary and a MNC > Network dictionary to check what those codes stand for

Can't help you out with Android though.. :)

Comment: Very useful, is there a way to find the country code ISO?

Comment: @user915829 I think you'll need to find or make a dictionary of MCC/MNC : country ISO yourself...